# Convert a SUMIFS to SUBTOTAL across two tables in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have been creating a home budget file in Excel but have hit a snag in one of my formulas and am hoping someone can help me solve this. I have seen a couple of answers on this forum, but have had no luck in incorporating the answers into my spreadsheet.

I have two tables, on separate Sheets and need to access the values from one table in another table:

Sheet(1) has the table named INCDATA

Sheet(2) has the table named IEINC

Table IEINC has the source (search) criteria to look for in table INCDATA.

I have the following formula that correctly sums the data between the two tables;

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(INCDATA,,MATCH(C$10,INCDATA[#Headers],0)),INCDATA[[Details]:[Details]],$B11)
```

What I am now trying to do is to either add this to, or change this to a "SUBTOTAL" function so that only visible rows are calculated when I filter the dates in table INCDATA

I have tried this formula, but get the wrong result;

```
=SUBTOTAL(109,INDEX(INCDATA,,MATCH(C$10,INCDATA[#Headers],0)),INCDATA[[Details]:[Details]],$B11)
```

That formula results in a Total of all Values displayed:
60.00 (Displayed in each row of the search criteria)

But what I am looking to do is add and display the individual search criterias based on the displayed rows when filtered.

Income01  10.00
Income02  20.00
Income03  30.00

Does anyone have any suggestions.

Comment: Hopefully this link to the file will work:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/liqjy7afg5r2vlu/House%20Budget%20-%20Copy.xlsm?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what your are looking for.

Change in Subtotal from 109 to 9.

```
=SUBTOTAL(9, ....
```

[Function of Subtotal:](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/subtotal-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939?NS=EXCEL&Version=16&SysLcid=1033&UiLcid=1033&AppVer=ZXL160&HelpId=xlmain11.chm60392&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

"Function_num     Required. The number 1-11 or 101-111 that specifies the function to use for the subtotal. 1-11 includes **manually-hidden** (filtred) rows, while 101-111 excludes them **(hidden/filtered rows)**; filtered-out cells are always excluded."

---

So converting this formula to take care of filtering it should go from:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(INCDATA,,MATCH(C$10,INCDATA[#Headers],0)),INCDATA[[Details]:[Details]],$B11)
```

to this, applied in Sheet "Income&Expenses" Cell: `H11`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(9, OFFSET('Income(Data)'!$C$5:$C$10,ROW('Income(Data)'!$C$5:C9)-MIN(ROW('Income(Data)'!$C$5:C9)),,1)),--('Income(Data)'!$B$5:B9=$B$11))
```

So when you apply filter on the sheet "Income(Data)":

[image]

It will only sum the applied filters in the "Income&Expenses":

[image]

Comment: If you down load the file and take a look at the tab called "INCOME&EXPENSES" you will see two tables. Under the column "Budget", the blue table has the second function *showing the use of 109, and the orange table shows the first function I mentioned. The table where the data is being fetched from is on the tab called "Income(Data)"

I did try change the number from 109 to 9, but this had no affect of the displayed totals

Comment: Thank you for this new formula. We are now one step closer to obtaining the needed end result. I applied your formula, but what it is now doing is adding the same value to each cell. So when filtered by date, each cell is getting the value of "10" or "13" depending on the date i selected.

What I need the formula to do is look in (Income&Expenses("B11...B12...B13") and then SubTotal that value in the (Income(Data)) sheet. So if "B11"= Income01 then Subtotal "Income01", then in "B12" the value is Income02, Subtotal Income02, and so on.

Comment: Just to clarify, I need the formula to work when filtered by DATE and not DETAILS

Comment: You are correct, the reason is because you have tables in the "Income&Expenses" sheet. Go to " Table Tools" -> "Design" -> "Convert to Range". Tables which you currently use now, applies the same formula across the whole column. You don't want that. Given Column Budget, you want each row to have their own formula. Therefore you need to remove the "Excel Tables"... In the formula I use ranges as `$C$5:$C$10`, not table names: `INCDATA[#Headers]`

Comment: I will try that, but I also removed the Static Command in the last cell reference in your formula --('Income(Data)'!$B$5:B11=$B$11)) to ('Income(Data)'!$B$5:B11=$B11))--and it worked as I needed it to.

Thank you so much for all your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Smart, yea. That could be a twist and if it works for you, go with that only and keep tables :)!! No problem.

Comment: Actually this gave me an idea now... this could actually work with table name references..., always worth a try ;) :
`=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(9, OFFSET(INCDATA[Budget],ROW(INCDATA[Budget])-MIN(ROW(INCDATA[Budget])),,1)),--(INCDATA[Details]=$B11))` same as above but using table references instead

Comment: I have tested it and you don't need to remove tables, my apologies. This is the solution: `$B11`, great catch by you :)!!!

Comment: Sorry, been away for a few days. Yeah, after looking at your formula I wanted to convert it to use tables, and I also ended up with the same formula you did:
    =SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(9, OFFSET(INCDATA[Budget],ROW(INCDATA[Budget])-MIN(ROW(INCDATA[Budget])),,1)),--(INCDATA[Details]=$B11))

Works perfectly and all I needed to do was to change the Table Names in the formula to get it to work across all the tables.

Again, may thanks for all your help. You are a gentleman amongst gentlemen good sir!   :-)

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out for you... what a small sign ($) can do, ahhaha. Thanks for the compliment, you too!! Good luck with your project, take care :)!!!!